# Suddenly Java process (JVM) got disconnected

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, tomcat7

I started my application in tomcat server with the following properties,

> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1502 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=../jmxremote.password -DinstanceName=$INSTANCE -Xms256m -Xmx2g -Dtomcat.appserver.instance=$INSTANCE -Dcontainer.port=$PORT -Dcontainer.host=`../hostname` -DappLogLevel=INFO -DappLogDir=/logs/ -DUseCustomErrorPage=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-PrintGCDetails -XX:-PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1028m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:HeapDumpPath=/dumps/ -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=300 -DUseCustomErrorPage=false

I have started the jconsole and suddenly 
[image]

I don't know for some reason JVM has stopped with no error.

Using Tomcat for deployment and JDK 8
Java: **jdk1.8.0_11_32bit**
Tomcat: **apache-tomcat-7.0.35**

please let me know if we can make any modifications to the environment settings.

Comment: did you check the logs from the application for around that time? Also, does this happen reproducably? have you tried running [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/) to see if it also gets disconnect? Another approach would be capturing the network via e.g. [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Someone tripped over the wire? Seriously, there are too many possibilities and too little information.

Comment: You're running a 32-bit process, with 2GB per-process address space. That means a max heap size of 2G is way too big. 1G might well fail, especially given that your other values are high as well. You need 64-bit to even have a chance of running this.